# Accessing single element in nested Dictionary

Tags: c#, ios, dictionary, xamarin

I have an iOS app where I am using a nested dictionary to supply data to a table view. The structure of the Dictionary is:

```
Dictionary<string1, Dictionary<string2, string3>> dict;
(I have named the strings here for clarification purposes)
```

I am currently having trouble accessing single elements in this nested Dictionary. I would like to have `string1` be the section title, `string2` to be the cell text label and `string3` to be the cell detail text label. Here is my current approach with the tables data source:

```
public class SupervisionDetailSource:UITableViewSource
{
    Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>> dict;
    string Identifier = "cell";

    public SupervisionDetailSource(Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>> dict)
    {
        this.dict = dict;
    }

    public override string TitleForHeader(UITableView tableView, nint section)
    {
        return dict.Keys.ElementAt((int)section);
    }

    public override UITableViewCell GetCell(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        UITableViewCell cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell(Identifier);
        if (cell == null)
            cell = new UITableViewCell(UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, Identifier);

        //this is not right
        cell.TextLabel.Text = dict[supvList.Keys.ElementAt(indexPath.Section)][dict[dict.Keys.ElementAt(indexPath.Row)]]; //string2
        cell.DetailTextLabel.Text = string3 ...?

        return cell;
    }

    public override nint RowsInSection(UITableView tableview, nint section)
    {
        string key = dict.Keys.ElementAt((int)section);
        return dict[key].Count;

    }

    public override nint NumberOfSections(UITableView tableView)
    {
        return dict.Keys.Count;
    }
}
```

Thank you for any help

Comment: What do you mean by "not right"?

Comment: @AMomchilov I mean my current approach to accessing `string2` of my dictionary is not right/not compilable

Comment: That doesn't tell me anything I didn't know already. Is it a compiler error? If so, what's the error message? Is it a run-time error? If so, what's the stack trace? Is it a logical error? If so, what's the actual output and the expected output?

Comment: `KeyNotFoundException`

Comment: Put in a break point in the debugger, and see the content of the Dictionary. See if it contains the key/value pair you expect. Also check that the key you're trying to use is valid

Answer (score 0):

I was having difficulty accessing the nested elements but I ended up getting it to work. I simply had a misunderstanding of how I needed to approach this problem(not to mention it gets a little hairy the more nested you go).

My Solution:

```
cell.TextLabel.Text = dict[dict.Keys.ElementAt(indexPath.Section)].Keys.ElementAt(indexPath.Row); //string2
cell.DetailTextLabel.Text = dict[dict.Keys.ElementAt(indexPath.Section)][dict[dict.Keys.ElementAt(indexPath.Section)].Keys.ElementAt(indexPath.Row)]; //string3
```

Comment: You should really try to clean that up a bit. It's pretty hairy.